# How to run Cucumber with OR AND Multiple tags

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have cucumber scenarios with examples.  Examples are split into using multiple tags like below:

```
Feature: ...
  Scenario Outline: ...
    ...    
    @Admin @INT
      Examples:
      ...    
    @Admin @EXT
      Examples:
      ...
    @User @EXT
      Examples:
      ...
    @User @INT
      Examples:
      ...
```

To run scenarios with tags `@Admin` AND `@EXT` I use

`...tags = {"@Admin","@EXT"}...`

How do I run scenarios with

`{"@Admin","@EXT"}` && `{"@User","@INT"}`, 
`{"@Admin","@EXT"}` || `{"@User","@INT"}`

Comment: Is `{"@Admin","@EXT"} && {"@User","@INT"}` supposed to run scenarios that are tagged with all four tags?

Comment: No, I would like to find and run scenarios tagged with `@Admin AND @EXT` (2 tags) followed by `@User AND @INT` (2 tags).  It is not same as `@Admin AND @EXT AND @User AND @INT`.

Comment: You could define two different runners (with 2 tags each) and run both of those?

Answer (score 31):

This change was introduced into cucumber-jvm 2.0.0 (2017-08-29)

*Support [Tag Expressions](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/tag-expressions) (part of #1035 Björn Rasmusson)*

```
Migrating from old style tags
--tags @dev stays the same
--tags ~@dev becomes --tags 'not @dev'
--tags @foo,@bar becomes --tags '@foo or @bar'
--tags @foo --tags @bar becomes --tags '@foo and bar'
--tags ~@foo --tags @bar,@zap becomes --tags 'not @foo and (@bar or @zap)'
```

So perhaps something like this:

```
-Dcucumber.options="--tags '(@Admin and @EXT) or (@User and @INT)'"
```

**EDIT**

For @CucumberOptions, the above would look like:

`tags = {"@tag"}` is unchanged

`tags = {"~tag"}` becomes `tags = {"not tag"}`

`tags = {"@tag1,@tag2")` becomes `tags = {"@tag1 or @tag2"}`

`tags = {"@tag1","@tag2"}` becomes `tags = {"@tag1 and @tag2"}`

`tags = {"@tag1","@tag2,@tag3"}` becomes `tags = {"@tag1 and (@tag2 or @tag3)"}`

Comment: Old question but one that others may have.

Comment: Thats interesting.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 thanks for this post . I was doing a small mistake by missing ' (single quote ) this wasted my day trying to figure out why its not working . But ur response worked . Thanks

Comment: Broken link.  Please fix.